# create function error in mysql [42000][1064]

Tags: mysql

I want to create a function in MySQL(**version**:5.7.21-log), the code like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION uf_sum(left INT, right INT)
  RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    RETURN left + right;
  END
```

But get an error message:

```
[2020-01-18 16:01:29] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left INT, right INT)
[2020-01-18 16:01:29] RETURNS INT
[2020-01-18 16:01:29] BEGIN
[2020-01-18 16:01:29] RETURN left + right;
[2020-01-18 16:01:29] END' at line 1
```

I searched on google, got a piece of code, it can be executed correctly:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION sp_cal_max(p_num1 INT, p_num2 INT)
  RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    IF p_num1 >= p_num2
    THEN
      RETURN p_num1;
    ELSE
      RETURN p_num2;
    END IF;
  END
```

I couldn't find the difference in syntax between this two-piece of SQL, and I couldn't find where's wrong,
.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left` and `right` are [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. Enclose them in back ticks.

```
CREATE FUNCTION uf_sum(`left` INT, `right` INT)
  RETURNS INT
  BEGIN
    RETURN `left` + `right`;
  END
```

Or rename them.